# In Java, how to specify generic type?

Tags: java, jpa, generics, abstract

I am trying to create a generic method that defines a search. The search will receive the field name and the value to be searched as input parameters, not the object itself.

The problem is that I am getting the following errors in the 'return' line:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type safety: The method from(Class) belongs to the raw type AbstractQuery. References to generic type AbstractQuery<T> should be parameterized
    - Type safety: The method where(Expression) belongs to the raw type CriteriaQuery. References to generic type CriteriaQuery<T> should be parameterized
    - Illegal class literal for the type parameter T
    - The method findOne(Example<S>) in the type QueryByExampleExecutor<T> is not applicable for the arguments (CriteriaQuery)
```

```
public abstract class ModelController<T extends HasId, R extends ModelRepository<T>> {

    private T _findId(String field, String needle) {
        EntityManager em;
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();

        // Here I got the errors
        return repository.findOne(cq.where(cb.equal(cq.from(T.class).get(field), needle))); 
    }
    
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: I don't think you can use T.class since T is a parameter and java uses Type Erasure in generics.

Answer (score 0):

You're issue lies with trying to access the class of `T` with `T.class`. Java erases type for generics which you can see in their [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) so the only way to get a class reference is to extend your method to take in a `Class<T>`.